# How to write a filter to search nested json in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I wrote a little program in angular using ui-select. And I want to write a filter that do an **OR** search in different fields (that can be nested fields in a json). In the github of ui-select I found this filter that can do a similar things (but only with simple fields) :

```
/**
 * AngularJS default filter with the following expression:
 * "person in people | filter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}"
 * performs an AND between 'name: $select.search' and 'age: $select.search'.
 * We want to perform an OR.
 */
app.filter('propsFilter', function() {
  return function(items, props) {
    var out = [];

    if (angular.isArray(items)) {
      var keys = Object.keys(props);

      items.forEach(function(item) {
        var itemMatches = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          var prop = keys[i];
          var text = props[prop].toLowerCase();
          if (item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
            itemMatches = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (itemMatches) {
          out.push(item);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Let the output be the input untouched
      out = items;
    }

    return out;
  };
});
```

My json object where I want to apply this filter has this structure :

```
$scope.contracts = [{
  name: "contract1.00",
  value: 10,
  id :{
    id : 8000,
    code : 2
  },
  policy : {
    info : {
      name : "test1",
      country : "test"
    }
  }
}
//other elements....
```

The problem is that this 'propsFilter' only works with simple fields. So, if I write this :

```
 propsFilter: {name: $select.search, value : $select.search}
```

It will work correcly and do an OR search in these two fields (name OR values). But in my example, I want to do the OR search with two others fields : id.id and policy.info.name.

So, what I want to do is to use a line like this :

```
propsFilter: {name: $select.search, value : $select.search, id.id : $select.search, policy.info.name : $select.search }
```

Finally, here is my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ej2r7XqeTPOC5d1NDXJn?p=preview

How can I do that in the same search filter??

Comment: Good one. But the scope of this question seems to be too broad.

Comment: Euh, I don't understand what you want to say, but my question was not really large. I just asked how can I apply this filter to nested properties like id.id and policy.info.name. I found that we can use something like recursive filters but I'm not really sure about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your plunker. First of all, break from the loop caused the filter to work only on first property `name`, I've also added a condition in the if `item[prop] &&` so your code doesn't throw an error when the property does not exist on the item

http://plnkr.co/edit/CwNANzodvjnuMCNyJYtA?p=preview

```
app.filter('propsFilter', function($parse) {
  return function(items, props) {
    var out = [];

    if (angular.isArray(items)) {
      var keys = Object.keys(props);

      items.forEach(function(item) {
        var itemMatches = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          var prop = $parse(keys[i])(item);
          var text = props[keys[i]].toLowerCase();

          if (prop && prop.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
            itemMatches = true;
          }
        }

        if (itemMatches) {
          out.push(item);
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Let the output be the input untouched
      out = items;
    }

    return out;
  };
});
```

Comment: thanks for you answer ! But this filter still don't work on the nested properties like id.id and policy.info.name. Can you please show me how can I fix that please? Thanks

Comment: My bad, haven't checked that, I've updated plunker, since the key might be in form of `id.id` the notation `item['id.id']` will look for `item = {'id.id': 1}` not `item = {id: { id: 1}}` but you can use angular `$parse` to check for attribut in context of item

Comment: YEES, it works! thank you @maurycy !!! one of the best angular answers that I had read here so far!!!!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ maurycy Can you see this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877264/how-can-i-make-this-filter-attached-to-scope-of-a-controller pleaase? I want to attach this filter to the scope of the controller rather than make it a generic filter. Can you pleaaase help me with that????